# Embedded Google doc pdf on Mac and safari displaying message second page onward Whoops! There was a pro-blem loading this page

Tags: macos, safari, google-document-viewer

I have embedded pdf file in google doc viewer in my application using below code.
http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

When displaying pdf in iframe on mac machine safari browser then only first page is displayed properly and from second page onward it display "Whoops! There was a problem loading this page " this message.

This problem occurs only mac machine safari browser. On mac chrome and firefox working fine. I am using MAC OSx10.8.5(12F45) and safari version 6.0.5

**But same working fine on another mac machine as OS x Yosemite Version 10.10.2, Safari Browser version 8.0.3**

Is problem is with OS version or safari browser version or google doc viewer and what is it? How to solve this issue?

Thanks